# I cannot get the Telerik MVC extensions grid to show a total with ClientFooterTemplate

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Ajax binding and so I am assuming that if I want the total to update after the user edits a change, I need the ClientFooterTemplate as opposed to just the FooterTemplate which works.

Here is my grid which works with FooterTemplate:

```
    @{
    GridEditMode mode = (GridEditMode)ViewData["mode"];
    GridButtonType type = (GridButtonType)ViewData["type"];
    GridInsertRowPosition insertRowPosition = (GridInsertRowPosition)ViewData["insertRowPosition"];
    Html.Telerik().Grid<RedFile.Models.QuickQuoteItemView>("items")
        .Name("QuoteItems")
        .DataKeys(k => k.Add(o => o.Id))
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(type).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" }))
        .Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Bound(o => o.Id).ReadOnly().Hidden();
            c.Bound(o => o.ItemID);
            c.Bound(o => o.Description);
            c.Bound(o => o.ItemQty);
            c.Bound(o => o.ItemPrice).Format("{0:c}");
            c.Bound(o => o.LineTotal)
                .Width(100)
                .Aggregate(ag => ag.Sum())
                .FooterTemplate(result => (result.Sum == null ? "0.00" : result.Sum.Format("{0:c}")))
                .Format("{0:c}");
            c.Command(s =>
            {
                s.Edit();
                s.Delete();
            });
        })
        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(mode).InsertRowPosition(insertRowPosition))
        .DataBinding(b => b.Ajax()
            .Select("GridSelect", "QuickQuote")
            .Insert("GridInsert", "QuickQuote", new { qqid = Model.Id })
            .Update("GridUpdate", "QuickQuote", new { qqid = Model.Id })
            .Delete("GridDelete", "QuickQuote", new { qqid = Model.Id })
            )
        .Footer(true)
        .Render();
}
```

If I change the footer template to something like this: (I have tried multiple variations with the same result)

```
                .ClientFooterTemplate("<#= $.telerik.formatString('{0:c}', Sum) #>")
```

The total simply disappears.

All I want is a total that updates after the user changes something.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ItemPrice)
                    .FooterTemplate(
                        @<text>
                            Total:@string.Format("{0:c}", Model.ItemPrice)
                        </text>
                    )
                    .Width(100)
                    .Format("{0:c}");
```

Refer to [**Teleriks MVC grid Documentation**](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/headerfootertemplates)

Comment: Hmm - I don't think that helps - it's not the ItemPrice column I'm trying to total (it's the LineTotal) and the value is not coming from the View's model, the grid has it's own data that it is getting from a ViewData object, so I'm not sure how to make this work - also, I can Get the FooterTemplate to work fine (other than the ajaxey updating) - it is the ClientFooterTemplate that I am trying to get to work...

Comment: if that is not price column then why are you formatting it as currency {0:c} ?

Comment: Note that I have since learned that I am using an old, discontinued version of this grid control, so I am in the process of switching it to something else anyway - depending on my success, this question is probably defunct

Comment: The LineTotal is also a currency column - LineTotal = ItemPrice * ItemQty

Comment: @MikeDeFehr paste your updated code with columns.Bound( for footer template